# Evaluate Limit involves Ln

Tags: limits

I evaluated using L'Hospital Rule and the result is 0 but i don't know i'm i was right or not, I'm newb to Calculus
$\lim _{x\to \:0^+}\left(x\cdot \ln \left(x\right)^5\right)$

Comment: The fifth power is on the logarithm and *not* on the $\;x\;$ in its argument, right?

Comment: Yes it is on the logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log^5x}{\frac1x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{5\log^4x}{-\frac1{x^2}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{20\log^3x}{\frac2{x^3}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\ldots$$

$$\ldots\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{120}{-\frac{120}{x^5}}=0$$

Comment: @PeterSkyrie , don't forget to upvote all the answers you find helpful and, eventually, **accept** the one you think is the best.